# Where to hook into woocommerce after payment is completed but before its verified

Tags: woocommerce, hook, payment

I have a client who is interested in creating some CPTs for each item in their customers order. I have found the hook woocommerce_order_status_completed() but some customers will be paying by check, and that hook doesn't fire until after the order is verified under Woocommerce>Orders.

My client would like the CPTs to be created before the check payment is verified. I've been searching woo's hook reference over and over and can't quite find what I'm looking for.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe `woocommerce_checkout_order_processed` or `woocommerce_pre_payment_complete`?

Comment: woocommerce_checkout_order_processed is the one I was looking for! Thanks!

If you submit that as an answer I will accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [`woocommerce_checkout_order_processed`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-checkout.php#L638) hook.